# Lower bound for a linear combination of two related complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I have been trying this problem for sometime. If $a, \;b,\;\alpha$   are   complex numbers such that $|a|\leq K|b|,$ and $|\alpha|\leq 1$ where $0\leq K\leq 1,$ then I want to express the lower bound for $|a+\alpha b|$ in terms of $\alpha, K$ and only  one of $|a|, |b|.$ I am able to get only for special case  like when $|b|\leq 1.$  Can there be a general lower bound of the above said type?

Comment: You don't want the lower bound to depend on $K$, and you want it to depend on $\alpha$ as well as only on one of $|a|$ and $|b|$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. you are right. But I missed 'K'  part in my question. I will rectify it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we give a bound in terms of $\alpha, K, |b|$. We assume first that $b \ne 0$, and write $w = a/b$. Then we know only that $|w| \leq K \leq 1$ and $|\alpha| \leq 1$. Thus
$$|a + \alpha b| = |wb + \alpha b| = |b||w + \alpha| \geq |b| \max(0,|\alpha| - |w|) \geq |b| \max(0,|\alpha| - K),$$
and this is the best possible lower bound. (If $|\alpha| \leq K$, we could have $\alpha + w = 0$.) This bound is also valid (and best) if $b = 0$.

Now we give a bound in terms of $\alpha, K, |a|$. We assume first that $K, a, \alpha \ne 0$. If we set $v = b/a$, we know only that $|v| \geq 1/K$. Now
$$|a + \alpha b| = |a + \alpha v a| = |a||1 + \alpha v| \geq |a|\max(0,|\alpha v| - 1) \geq |a| \max(0,|\alpha|/K - 1),$$
and this is the best lower bound that can be achieved. (If $|\alpha|/K \leq 1$, we could have $\alpha v = -1$.) If $a = 0$, then this expression is also the best lower bound since $|b|$ can be as small as we like. If $K = 0$, then $a = 0$, so the best lower bound is $0$. If $\alpha = 0$, then the lower bound is $|a|$.

Comment: The results obtained by David are sharp when $|\alpha|\geq K.$ But for $|\alpha|<K $ is there any sharper bound than '0'? Because for $\alpha=0,$ $|a+\alpha b|=|a|,$ but the above result gives the lower bound $0.$

Comment: You are correct if $\alpha = 0$, with respect to the bound in terms of $|a|$. I will edit my answer to reflect this. But if $0<|\alpha| \leq K$, then $b = -a/\alpha$ satisfies the hypotheses, so no bound better than $0$ can be given in terms of $K$, $\alpha$ and $|a|$.

Comment: There are few special cases I think. Suppose if $|a|\leq K |\alpha b|$, then it can be easily seen that  $|a+\alpha b|\geq |\alpha b|-|a|\geq (1-K)|\alpha b|.$ Now the remaining part is  the case $|a|> K |\alpha b|!$